# How to compile Node.js and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, visual-studio

I will be working on a project that includes Node.js, Angular and Mongo DB. I have been working in .Net environment for past 15+ years so this would be new world for me. So I have few questions.

1. What IDE is recommended for Node.js & Angular? I am pretty comfortable using Visual Studio and I have noticed VS has extensions so I can use it for Node.js & Angular. It has intellisense & shows compile time errors too.  Is VS recommended or is there any better IDE available?
2. Coming from .Net world, all .Net projects must be compiled  before you deploy them. Is this not true for Node.js or Angular projects? We don’t need to compile them? I have noticed my team member just copies the whole folder ( which has code)  to prod server and that’s it. No compilation, No bin folder, No release folder.
3. I am Planning to use Jenkins for deployment, so if 2nd question is true then I guess I just have to write script that will copy the code to destination. ( and manipulate the config files accordingly based on environment)

Answer (score 1):

If you have already worked on .NET (specifically ASP.NET) then learning Node.js And AngularJS wouldn't be hardle.

1. I would recomment using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
2. No need to build and deploy. but if you are already aware of visual studio nuget package manager then npm is similar to it. and you probably need to download package dependencies for your project. Nothing related to build process but it's totally relevant with .NET package references and nuget packages.
3. Yes you can just write script that will copy the code to destination

Answer (score 1):

1> If you are more comfortable with Visual Studio, then you can use [Nodejs plugin for VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx). There is popular Microsoft Visual Code text editor as well. I prefer to use Sublime Text.

2> No, there is no need of compilation. All are javascript files that runs V8 engine.

3> Yes, you need to copy the files to required location.

Comment: VS Code vs Nodejs plugin for VS. Which one should i use? I already have Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Its upto you. If you are more used to VS, then install Nodejs plugin for VS. It may help you.

Comment: So i have installed extension for Node.Js in visual studio. However how do i open existing node.js project which is not created using Visual Studio? There are several other developers (crowd) working on the same project and they are using different IDE. Visual studio needs "njsproj" file to open existing project. I thought after installing plugin i will be able to open/browse it as "folder" instead of project